# "Segmentation fault" during "import cv" on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, opencv, macports

Trying to compile opencv on my Mac from source.

I have following CMakeCache.txt:
http://pastebin.com/KqPHjBx0

I make `ccmake ..`, press `c`, then `g`.
Than I make `sudo make -j8`:
http://pastebin.com/cJyr1cEd

Than I make `sudo make install`:
http://pastebin.com/W77syYBj

And than I make `import cv` in python and get "Segmentation faul" with this stacktrace:
http://pastebin.com/gegYAK1u

I don't know what could be useful to help me, pls. ask, I'll get it.

Comment: Hey, how did you create that stack trace?

Answer (score 8):

I had a same situation and resolved the following steps.

In ccmake(`ccmake -G "Unix Makefiles" .`), toggle to the advanced mode pressing `t`.

change `PYTHON_LIBRARY` value to `/opt/local/lib/libpython2.6.dylib` and `PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR` to `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6`.

Note that the specific path depends, of course, what version of Python you are using (2.6 or 2.7 etc.). Also, if you are using the system Python, instead of MacPorts (which is in /opt), then you probably want **PYTHON_LIBRARY** to  be  **/usr/lib/libpython2.6.dylib**

Comment: this seemed to fix it for me, even though the `'make install'` errored out. go figure.

Comment: I had the same error, but couldn't understand this answer. But typing `sudo port select --set python python27` fixed the segfault for me.

Comment: In my case, I don't have MacPorts Python, but rather the python.org Python. I just rewrote the symlink at `/usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib` to point to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python` instead of `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python`.

Answer (score 1):

From your logs, you seem to use MacPorts and python 2.6.

`opencv` will compile fine on this framework:

```
sudo port install  opencv +python26
```

be sure to have `py26-numpy` installed to have support for basic functions such as `cv.fromarray` :

```
sudo port install py26-numpy
```

means that your problem has been solved by the MacPorts community.  is it a problem of the latest source? the version you compile is the one (opencv 2.2.0) used by macports.

Your question is about compiling from source. Looking at the portfile linked to that you'll be able to locate your problem. to find the Portfile, do:

```
port file opencv
```

or directly

```
sudo port edit  opencv
```

this will list all configuration flags necessary for a working openCV.

Comment: I tried different variations already and many of them failed with different results. I have messy system right now.
 ---- 
I have python_select installed. It has 2 variants of python26: python26-apple and python26. If -apple one selected I have situation described in this post. 
 --- 
Having selected second I have this http://pastebin.com/ve7wjFy5.
 --- 
Here is what import paths python26 has: http://pastebin.com/1kggWJZB

Python26-apple has: http://pastebin.com/eDmXfpgg

Comment: Just in case - here where i get opencv mentioned under /opt/: http://pastebin.com/Qij5kuFt
 --- 
Here is where I have cv.so already: http://pastebin.com/Di8MvSJj

Answer (score 0):

Typing:

```
sudo port select --set python python27
```

fixed the segfault for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple, macports did rewrote cv.so in ~/usr/lib

if you installed OPENCV using

```
sudo port install  opencv +python26
```

type

```
sudo port select --set python python26
```

if you installed OPENCV using

```
sudo port install  opencv +python27
```

type

```
sudo port select --set python python27
```

The "bug" is that python2.7 interpreter is trying to open python2.6 pre-compiled binary that gives seg fault 11 (or vice versa)

The nevereinding problem with opencv is that it does not have source code, just binaries that are stongly dependent on which compiler there were built on (which platform etc.)