# Python "Segmentation fault: 11" when running "import cv" or "import cv2"

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, opencv, macports

I have installed numpy and opencv using macports as per [these instructions,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410443/how-to-install-python-2-7-bindings-for-opencv-using-macports) but when I try `import cv` or `import cv2` I just get the segfault and I have no idea why.

**Any suggestions?**

---

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv
Segmentation fault: 11
```

---

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Sorry there are so few details, but this is a new computer and I installed macports on it just for this, and these are the only things I've installed with macports, so I have no idea why this isn't working.

---

## Edit: Now I'm More Confused.

Looking through the crash report I found this:

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
```

So, as a shot in the dark, I ran python as super user:

```
$ sudo python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 13 2014, 15:13:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv
>>>
```

As super user, everything appears to run fine. How is this possible?

Comment: Try to fix permissions for your libs, as I see only root can access them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely to the info message of your python command, you will see the difference.

From the buggy one:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Segmentation fault: 11
```

From the working one:

```
$ sudo python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 13 2014, 15:13:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv
>>>
```

You have two different versions of Python on your machine which might explain the behaviors you got.

Comment: Good eye, I didn't catch that... How can I make my regular Python command point where the super user Python points?

Comment: Uhm, I found [this](http://sevas.github.io/2011/06/14/multiple-python-osx.html) and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/35256/how-can-i-change-the-default-python-version-on-snow-leopard) discussing about some solutions. Maybe you will find them helpful.

Comment: Thanks so much, `defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Version 2.7.9` was the command I needed.

Answer (score 1):

After hitting this problem on OSX 10.11 and trawling through several cases of this problem in various contexts, I realized that this problem happens due to following independent reasons mostly:

1. conflicting python versions (more than one pythons); solution - uninstall one of them, get the one thats compatible with opencv (["Segmentation fault" during "import cv" on Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242257/segmentation-fault-during-import-cv-on-mac-os))
2. opencv version issue; solution - get the right version for you [Python opencv feature detector causes segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674938/python-opencv-feature-detector-causes-segmentation-fault)
3. issue with your numpy version; solution - uninstall and install numpy again ([OpenCV - cannot find module cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/opencv-cannot-find-module-cv2))

I tried all 3 but number 3 solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(False)
```

at the beginning of the code solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was simply

```
sudo apt install python3-opencv
```

and then install pip opencv package

```
sudo pip3 install opencv-python
```

or

```
sudo pip install opencv-python
```

Note: This was because I have launched a new Aws instance.

Comment: `sudo pip install` is bad form. You should use a virtualenv, even in a standalone instance. It has way too much potential to cause headaches.

Comment: Agreed, back then I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the similar problem.

```
➜  ~ ✗ python
Python 3.6.0 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec 23 2016, 13:19:00)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
[1]    41233 segmentation fault  python
```

But if I import numpy first, the problem will go away.

```
➜  ~ ✗ python
Python 3.6.0 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec 23 2016, 13:19:00)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import cv2
>>>
```